# Copying files to Documents Directory results in failure

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, directory, documents

I recently started playing around with the iPhone file system, at first I had some trouble understanding some concepts but I think that in the end I got them straight and flowing.

My problem is that I am trying to copy a file from the mail app (or any app that opens my app with a file type my app supports) by implementing the `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:` method to the Documents Directory (`NSDocumentDirectory`), but my app seems to fail when doing this.

I created a `BOOL` with the value that my file manager returns when copying the file (`[fileManager copyItenAtPath:filePath toPath:newFilePath error:&error];` where newFilePath is my Documents Directory) and then check against it, and then NSLog if there was failure or success, I always get failure.

In an attempt to find out what was going on with my Documents directory I enabled file sharing, and instead of seeing the file I copied, I get an Inbox folder, and upon copying that folder to the Desktop I see that my files are in there. Why is this behavior? How can I get the result that I want?

I read somewhere in Apple documentation that when `UIDocumentInteractionController` opens a file it copies it to the Inbox folder, but obviously, my app does not make use of `UIDocumentInteractionController`.

Thank you in advance, your help is very much appreciated.

---

EDIT STARTS HERE

Here is my original code:

```
//AppDelegate.m
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication (NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
    rootFolder.fileURLFromLaunch = url; //Passing the URL on to aproperty on a different class
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ApplicationDidOpenFile" object:nil]; // notifying that the URL was passed and a file was opened
    return YES;
}
```

This is the class that does all the work with the file:

```
//RootFolder.m

- (void)copyFileIntoApp
{

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *filePath = [fileURLFromLaunch path];

    NSString *displayName = [filePath lastPathComponent];

    NSError *error = NULL;

    NSString *finalFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsPath, displayName];

if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:finalFilePath]) {

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"File already exists!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];

} else {

    BOOL success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:filePath toPath:finalFilePath error:&error];
    if (success) {

        NSLog(@"success");
        Document *document = (Document *) [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Document" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

        [document setFilename:displayName];

        [document setPath:finalFilePath];

        if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {

            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Please try again or restart the app" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alert show];
            [alert release];
        }

        [fileArray insertObject:document atIndex:0];

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];

        [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                              withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];

    } else {
        NSLog(@"failure %@ ", [error localizedDescription]);
    }


}
```

}

I hope that sets things more clearly.

Comment: What error message do you get when it fails?

Comment: nothing, I just created an `if...else` loop in which if the `BOOL` results `YES` I do `NSLog(@"success");` and if it results NO I do `NSLog(@"failure");`

Comment: Can you log the error using `[error localalizedDescription]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I get an Inbox folder, and upon copying that folder to the Desktop I see that my files are in there. Why is this behavior? How can I get the result that I want?

Because your app is sandboxed and does not have access to files that are not in its own directory. When the user tells iOS that he wants to open a file with a specific app iOS copies the file into the inbox directory.

---

Post the complete code of `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:`.
Your "I'm doing this and that" is not very helpful because there is a flaw between this and that. The algorithm you explained with your words is correct, but there is clearly a bug in your implementation.

So please post the full code of this method.

---

Edit: I tested the relevant parts of your code and they seem to work.

I would check that `fileManager` is not nil. That would explain why you don't see an error message.

Comment: Ok, based on what you just said, I seem to be approaching this from the wrong angle: What I'm doing is trying to copy the file directly from its location within the mail app, but now that you tell that apps that open files get a copy of the file in their inbox folder, I suppose i should be moving the file from the inbox folder into the Documents directory, right? Either way I'll post my code. I'll try approaching this differently and post my findings.

Comment: I can' post large blocks of code in the comments, I'll post it in the OP.

Comment: @Arturo the code is more useful in the question anyway. I tested your code and it works for me. But I had to make a few changes to get it working, so these could hide some bugs. For example I had to create a local NSFileManager instance, so check that `fileManager` isn't nil in your code. Maybe you forgot to init it somewhere.

Comment: I NSLogged the value of my NSFileManager and it indeed had a value of `NULL`, after alloc initing it was no longer null. Today, when I get home I'll test the new code and let you know my results.

Comment: Thank you, this was indeed the problem!!

Answer (score 1):

Are you setting your error to null upon instantiation? If you don't the memory that the `NSError` points to will not be NULL, and your logic will be tripped.

Do this:

```
NSError *error = NULL;
```

NOT this:

```
NSError *error;
```

Comment: I instantiated it to nil, I'll try with `NULL` and see what happens